# Constructors and Strings Part 2Letter Example

Tags: java

The issue I'm having is, while I believe that I've have set up everything correctly in the constructor, when I try to call the instance variable `from` of my new `Letter` instance `fromto` I seem to keep getting an error saying that the compiler can not find variable `fromto`. The goal is to get `Dylan` to appear in with the Text.

```
public class Letter {
    private String from; // Sets from instance variable to be stored
    private String to; /// Sets to instance vaariable to be stored


    public Letter(String from, String to) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;

    }
    public Letter() {

        Letter fromto = new Letter("Dylan", "April");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Dear " + fromto.from);

    }

}
```

Comment: Your `public Letter()` is a constructor. You don't instantiate your object from a constructor.  You do it from another class.  In order for the program to run, it needs to be places in a `main` method.

Comment: For future reference: It's better to edit your question if it's unclear or people ask for more information. It's better to post a new question if you're actually asking about something different.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, you should probably learn more about variable scope in Java. (Reading [Sun's tutorials about Object-oriented Java-programming](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html) is probably a good idea)

The problem here is that the variable `fromto` is declared in a constructor and thus is **only available from the scope of the constructor**. Instead, get rid of that constructor (unless you really want to keep it, in which case you should make sure to initialize your `from` and `to` variables properly) and move the variable to your `main` function.

```
public class Letter {
    private String from; // Sets from instance variable to be stored
    private String to; /// Sets to instance vaariable to be stored


    public Letter(String from, String to) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Letter fromto = new Letter("Dylan", "April");
        System.out.println("Dear " + fromto.from);
    }

}
```

Comment: Well thank you for the help. Our school has implemented a new teaching method which involves learning it ourselves and showing up Monday with questions. The idea being less class time learning and more time clarifying and working on difficulties. On a side note, why didn;t it work before? If I made it public doesn't that mean the values can be used?

Comment: @user2872518 The constructor was public which means that **it [the constructor]** can be used. However, the `Letter fromto` variable is declared as a **local variable** within a **method**. Local variables can **never** be accessed from outside the method (or more precisely, *code-block*) that they are declared in.

Answer (score 3):

You need to instantiate your `Letter` in the right scope. If you only need it inside the main method, the best place to create your instance is right at the beginning of the method block:

```
public class Letter {

    private String from; // Sets from instance variable to be stored
    private String to; /// Sets to instance vaariable to be stored

    public Letter(String from, String to) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;

    }

    public Letter() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Letter letter = new Letter("Dylan", "April");
       System.out.println("Dear " + letter.from);
    }

}
```

About the no-args constructor, it is a good practice to declare one if the instance variables `from` and `to` are optional, so that you can also instantiate letter with the syntax `new Letter()`. If you do not declare any constructors, the compiler provides a empty constructor by default.

Actually, whenever you can, it is a good thing to follow JavaBeans conventions. Quoting [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans):

> - The class must have a public default constructor (no-argument). This
>   allows easy instantiation within editing and activation frameworks.
> - The class properties must be accessible using get, set, is (used for
>   boolean properties instead of get) and other methods (so-called
>   accessor methods and mutator methods), following a standard naming
>   convention. This allows easy automated inspection and updating of bean
>   state within frameworks, many of which include custom editors for
>   various types of properties. Setters must receive only one argument.
> - The class should be serializable. It allows applications and
>   frameworks to reliably save, store, and restore the bean's state in a
>   fashion independent of the VM and of the platform.

Comment: It is not always a good thing to follow JavaBeans conventions, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114903/are-java-beans-as-data-storage-classes-bad-design)

Answer (score 3):

You need to first create a new instance of your Letter class before you can invoke fields and getter/setter-methods on that instance/object.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Letter myLetter = new Letter();
    System.out.println(myLetter.from);
}
```

Note the call on your private field from only succeeds as main is defined in the same class and therefore the created `myLetter` provides access to the field.

In practice you would define public setters and getters to access the private field.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
 public Letter(){

  Letter fromto= new Letter("Dylan", "April");

 }
```

then:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
Letter fromto= new Letter("Dylan", "April");
  System.out.println("Dear " + fromto.from);

  }
```